# How do I create condition in form of query to update method to avoid duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Is there any method in mongodb or mongoose so i can create conditional query to avoid repetition**
How can I bypass this below given code if "User" with same name 
     present in collection without using middleware
     Since,middleware directly skips the form filling page
**

```
 router.get('/page/:id/:username'/foo,
   function(req,res){

     //How can I bypass this below given code if "User" with same name 
     //present in collection without using middleware
     //Since,middleware directly skips the form filling page

    User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username},
    {
        $addToSet:{
           "messages":{
             User:req.params.username,
             id:req.params.id
           }
        }
     }, 
     function(err,user) {
        if (err) {
        throw err;
        } else {
         res.render("Form");
     })            
   })

      //I have to skip the first User.findOneAndUpdate method if it is 
      //already present

  router.post('/page/:id/:username'/foo/post,
    function(req,res){


      User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username,
          "messages.User":req.pa
           rams.username},
       {
          $push:{
                  "messages.$.texts":{
                              message:req.body.message,
                              username:req.user.username
                          }

               }
       },function(err,user){
            if (err) {
                 throw err;
             } else {
                 res.render("Form",{user:user});
             }
       })
    })


    //this is what my model look-like

      messages:[{
                  id:{
                     type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                     ref : "User"
                    },

                  texts:[{
                      username:String,
                      message:String
                  }],
                  User:String
            }],
```

Is there any condition that I can put in form of query in mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I,ve done it using .some() syntax ,I hope this solution helps other newbies like me **`

```
` 
router.post('/profile/chat/:username/:id/send',isLoggedIn,
 function(req,res){

  User.findById(req.user._id,function(err,primaryUser){
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
 } else {


  if (primaryUser.messages.some((message) => message.id.toString() 
    === req.params.id.toString())) {


 User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username,
 "messages.id":req.params.id},
{$push:
{"messages.$.texts":

{
message:req.body.message,
username:req.user.username
}

}
},function(err,user){
if (err) {
console.log(err);
} else {

 User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.params.username,
 "messages.id":req.user.id},
{$push:
{"messages.$.texts":

{
message:req.body.message,
username:req.user.username
}

}
},function(err,user){
if (err) {
throw err;
} else {

 console.log("Debugg Point 3"); 

}
})   
console.log("Debugg Point 4");
res.redirect("back");
}
})


 } else {




  var primarySpace = {
     id:req.params.id,
     User:req.params.username
   }

   primaryUser.messages.push(primarySpace);
   primaryUser.save();


   User.findById(req.params.id,function(err,secondaryUser){
     if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {

   var secondarySpace = {
     id:req.user._id,
     User:req.user.username
   }

   secondaryUser.messages.push(secondarySpace);
   secondaryUser.save();


 User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.user.username,
 "messages.id":req.params.id},
{$push:
{"messages.$.texts":

 {
 message:req.body.message,
 username:req.user.username
 }

 }
  },function(err,user){
 if (err) {
 throw err;
 } else {

 User.findOneAndUpdate({username:req.params.username,
  "messages.id":req.user.id},
  {$push:
  {"messages.$.texts":

    {
 message:req.body.message,
 username:req.user.username
   }

}
},function(err,user){
if (err) {
throw err;
} else {

 console.log("Debugg Point 1"); 

}
})   
console.log("Debugg Point 2");
res.redirect("back");
}
})  
    }
   })    
  }    
    }
  })

})
```